# Image in gridlayout kivy

Tags: python, image, kivy, grid-layout

I am trying to create a 10x10 grid of images in kivy but I find that all the images are separated by a large black border.It appears that the images remain at a constant 0f 100x100 pixels.

The code I have used so far does not include a .kv file:

```
class SkyBox(BoxLayout):

    def update(self):

        for i in range(100):
            self.children[len(self.children)-1].add_widget(Image(source=random.choice(["rock.png","rock2.png"]))

class SkyGame(Widget):
    def run(self):
        box=SkyBox()

        box.add_widget(GridLayout(cols=10))

        box.update()

        return box

class SkyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return SkyGame().run()


if __name__=="__main__":
    SkyApp().run()
```

It must also be noted that my end result requires multiple boxlayouts to be created in the update function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.children[len(self.children)-1]
```

This can be written more concisely and clearly as `self.children[-1]`.

```
add_widget(Image(source=random.choice(["rock.png","rock2.png"]))
```

The image widget does not by default stretch the image beyond its real dimensions (in this case, apparently 100x100). To change this, simply set its `allow_stretch` property:

```
 add_widget(Image(source=random.choice(["rock.png","rock2.png"], allow_stretch=True))
```

If you want to allow it to stretch by different amounts in different directions, you can add `keep_ratio=False` as well.

Comment: Thank you.It appeared I had not tried the combination of "allow_stretch" and "keep_ratio".